# How can one estimate the percentage of trades that are performed using algorithmic trading?

Tags: algorithmic-trading

Some studies try to estimate the percentage of trades that are  performed using algorithmic trading, [e.g.](https://youtu.be/V43a-KxLFcg?t=1m57s)

[image]

How can one estimate the percentage of trades that are  performed using algorithmic trading?

Comment: Perhaps Mr. Gourley or http://www.aitegroup.com/ will tell you how they came up with these figures.